# how to fix index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4?

Tags: python, arrays

I have two array in python, name is `data2004` and `data2011`. I want to append data in 2004 to 2011. but I get error like this *IndexError: index 66 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 66*. my array like this

```
adddata = []
data2004 = [2,3,4,5]
data2011 = [6,7,8,9,10]
for d2 in range(0, len(data2011[d2])):
    adddata.append(list([data2004[d2], data2011[d2]])
```

I know data2004 just have 4 data and data2011 have 5 data, but I when if data2004 in last array change to 0. and the the result like this

```
adddata = [[2,6], [3,7], [4,8], [5, 9], [0, 10]]
```

please help me, thank you

Comment: Indexes start from 0. So if the size is 4, indexes go from 0 to 3.

Comment: Your code requires the variables to contain lists of lists, not list of numbers.

Comment: ```data2011``` have 4 index, and ```data2004``` have 3 index. how to replace ```data2004``` to 4 index?

Comment: If you alter your `data2004` list then you will alter your result too.

Comment: btw What is the expected result?

Comment: @imraklr The expected result is at the end of the question.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel help?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the index is in range of `data2004`, and use `0` if it isn't.

```
for d2 in range(0, len(data2011)):
    for r2 in range(0, len(data2011[d2])):
        if d2 < len(data2004):
            adddata.append([data2004[d2][r2], data2011[d2][r2]])
        else:
            adddata.append([0, data2011[d2][r2]])
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, from your answer I got a picture and I managed to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:

```
 adddata = [list(e) for e in list(itertools.zip_longest(data2004, data2011, fillvalue = 0 ))]
```